# Text in CKEditor disappears

Tags: ckeditor

I have one question.

I use CKEditor 4.1 for replace textarea. When open page with CKEditor then text in CKeditor disappears.

Like this:

Before loading:
[image]

Afrer loading:

[image]

After loading CKEditor not work.

Any idea why?

Comment: No details - no idea. Upload sample page that shows this issue and describe how it can be reproduced and on which browser and we will be able to help.

Comment: The same works in all browsers. The problem does not always appears. Sometimes it works perfectly.

Comment: Now I used setTimeout function and works.

Comment: So I presume that you're doing some operations which should be done after waiting for specific events like `instanceReady`.

Comment: Add an answer if you found a solution @DanielJaušovec

Comment: You're probably setting the data in the editor without waiting for the editor or the instance to be fully loaded, the setTimeout is luckily giving you enough time for the instance to load. A better way is to attach to instanceReady and do setData operations.

Comment: Do anyone have solution how to solve problem with instanceReady function?

Answer (score 0):

I have solve the problem with setTimeout function

```
<script type="text/javascript">
setTimeout(function(){
    CKEDITOR.replace('textarea');
},1000);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set text within Html tag calling ckeditor.js

```
<div class="columns">
<div class="editor">
<div cols="10" id="editor1" name="editor1" rows="10"  contenteditable="true">
"Your Text Here...."
</div>
</div>
```

Then load you will see the text element inside of  "div" Element.